# Using 301 for only some content on a site that eventually will delete those pages?

Tags: redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

My company is migrating content from one section "A" of its gigantic website to a new website "B" which is focused only on this type of content. Eventually, they want to delete this old section "A" completely but the gigantic website will otherwise remain.

Is it worth using 301 redirects to help users get to the new site B, rather than pull the rug out one day, and to retain some of the page rank?

What about when that section A on the old site is completely deleted? Will the 301 rank stay with the new site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a good practice to create 301 redirect. It's good for both users and Search Engines. Also, it shows that you're not duplicating content, and Search Engines really don't like websites that "copy-paste" content from others.

As soon as search engines detect the 301, the rank will stay and they won't considerer it as duplicated content.